# Nginx proxy_pass to another upstream based on request uri

Tags: nginx, webserver, proxypass

I have two upstreams named `frontendcluster` and `admincluster` i want to do this:

if the request uri contains `/admin` or `/upload` or the request method is `POST` then use admincluster. else proxy pass to frontendcluster.

how can i do this in my conf file?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in nginx like...

```
  location /admin {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }

  location /upload {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }

  if ($request_method = POST) {
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }
```